# Compact set and closed set proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and let $X$ be compact.
>   Prove that the set $$X+Y=\{x+y:x\in X, y\in Y\}$$ is closed.

I know in order to prove this I must show that $X+Y$ contains all of its cluster points, but I am having difficulty showing that. Since $X$ is compact there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to some $x\in X$ thus that part is done in proving, but then how can I show that $Y$ converges to some $y\in Y$ and then show it also for $X+Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to show that the limit of every convergent sequence of the form $\{x_k + y_k\}$ with $x_k \in X$, $y_k \in Y$ belongs to $X + Y$.
As you have observed, we can pick a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$. We know that both sequences $x_{n_k}$ and $x_{n_k} + y_{n_k}$ converges. What does this mean for $y_{n_k}$?

Comment: But why does $x_{n_k} + y_{n_k}$ converge? Do we assume that?

Comment: Because it is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $x_k + y_k$.

Comment: So how do I state that formally? Do I say, suppose $x_{n_k} + y_{n_k}$ converges to some $z$ and the rest will follow?

Comment: Yes. You have $x_k + y_k \to z$, $x_{n_k} \to x$. Then, $x_{n_k} + y_{n_k} \to z$. Hence, $y_{n_k} \to z-x$.

Comment: One last question, do we have to pick a subsequence that converges? Cant we just pick a sequence?

Comment: You need the convergence of the subsequence $x_{n_k}$. The sequence $x_k$ itself does not (necessarily) converge.